# Append line by line text

Tags: notepad++

I've two files one with content -

```
Bob
Mike
John
```

Other with content -

```
Sesek
Wang
Bel
```

I want copy content of second file and append them line by line in first file like -

```
Bob Sesek
Mike Wang
John Bel
```

How can I achieve it using Notepad++?

Comment: Not directly possible in Notepad++, but if you know Python then you can script this using [Python Script - Plugin for Notepad++](http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done in multiple step process:

1. open both file
2. select the names from second file with column mode edition

   - <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>
   - With the mouse, select the block that conatins all the names
   - Copy <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
3. Go to first file (with firstnames)

   - <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>
   - With the mouse, select a block ahead the firstnames
   - Paste <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

Comment: +1 Arggg!! You beat me to it

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio: Thank you, next time it will be your turn ;)

Comment: Thanks @Toto for the solution!